# Replace text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of proxies that are in the following format: proxy(colon)port number (ie:109.188.139.33:8080). Can anyone tell me how to remove the colon and port number in Notepad++ so I'm just left with the proxy? I know how to do this in Excel but I would rather do it in Notepad++ if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you have **each proxy address on one line**, this is the simplest solution:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> for **Find/replace** dialog
2. **Find what:** `:.*$`      (it is string of any characters (`.*`) between semicolon and end of line -
   `$`)
3. **Replace with:** (empty)
4. Select **Regular Expression** and press **Replace All** button

Comment: Hi, yes, the proxies are on separate lines so this is just what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2205555 - for benefit of the community, please mark the most helpful answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

In npp, press **Ctrl-H**, then:

Find what: `:\d+`
Replace with: `Nothing`

Don't forget to check `Regular Expression` and click on `Replace all`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in notepad++

1) Press **ctrl+F**

2) Use the second tab in the box opened called "**Replace**"

3) Give :8080 in the box "**Find what**"

4) Delete the contents of box "**Replace with**", which means all the occurrences of ":8080 are replaced with a space or null

5) Click "**Find Next**" (*which finds the next occurrence*),then click "**Replace**" (*which replace the occurrence found*).

6) OR click "**Replace all**" which replaces all the occurrences concurrently

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex search will do what you're looking for:

Find:

```
([\d]{1,3})\.([\d]{1,3})\.([\d]{1,3})\.([\d]{1,3}):[\d]+
```

Replace:

```
\1.\2.\3.\4
```

Breaking this down bit by bit for you:

`(` - starts a new group. These are indexed starting from 1, and are later able to be referenced using `\n` where `n` is the group index. So `\1` will reference the first group, `\2` the second, etc.
`[\d]` - finds a digit.
`{1,3}` - this specifies that we want to find between 1 and 3 of the preceding search. So we're looking for 1-3 consecutive digits.
`)` - ends the group. Anything between `(` and `)` is part of this group.
`\.` - this matches a literal period. The backslash escapes the period; otherwise it would match any character.

Repeating this bit of Regex four times, we get a search for 1-3 digits (group #1), then a period, then 1-3 digits (group #2), then a period, then 1-3 digits (group #3), then a period, then 1-3 digits (group #4). All together, this matches something like `109.188.139.33`.

Now for the last bit:

`:` - matches a literal colon.
`[\d]+` - matches digits again, except the `+` specifies that we want one or more digits.

This bit looks for a port number; it will match something like `:8080` or `:35`. This is where the Regex truly shines compared to a regular search, because this will match *any* port number, not a fixed one.

Now for the replace:

`\1`, `\2`, `\3`, and `\4` match the parenthesized groups from the Find. So we're copying these groups back to where they came from, putting periods in between. We're basically reconstructing the IP address, but leaving the colon and port number out.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this, but it's a bit too complicated a solution for me.

Comment: @user2205555 Is there any way I can make it simpler for you or explain it better? If my understanding of your problem is correct, this should just be a simple copy & paste into Notepad++'s find and replace dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Replace All` in Notepad++ to replace all `:` followed by your port number with `" "`